# Can I safely compare standardized coefficients between datasets with differents numbers of observations?

Tags: interpretation, standardization

For simplicity, let's say that I regress Y on X using OLS in three different datasets, which all have different numbers of observations (1200, 1500 and 1900 respectively).

In all three datasets, I standardized both X and Y (and also possible control variables), so the coefficients I am getting are standardized.

I heard that one advantage of standardized coefficients is that they allow you to compare coefficients between datasets. But I am not 100% sure of this, hence why I am asking here.

Question 1 : if I observe that the coefficient of X is 0.3 in dataset 2 and 0.8 in dataset 3, can I safely say that the correlation between X and Y is stronger in dataset 3 than in dataset 2 ?

Question 2 : can this difference in coefficients be entirely due to the differences in sample size, or does standardization help mitigate the effect of sample size ? For example, let's say that Y is "university ranking" (with each dataset being a different university ranking) and X is "GDP per capita".
Taking the example from question 1 again, can I say that ranking 3 is more correlated with GDP per capita on average than ranking 2, or is there a high chance that this difference in coefficients can be attributed to the difference in sample sizes ?